# Rails_Admin - How to edit each key of a Jsonb as a field?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonb, rails-admin

I have a jsonb attribute in my model, called config_params.
`config_params: {key_a: 1, key_b: 100}`

I need to edit it in rails_admin, but I need to edit each key as a different field.
key_a a field and key_b another, and if exists.

The question is because each config_param can hold different keys, it makes as if I need to know the object before building the fields and I can't only build virtual fields. It needs to do dynamic.

I created dynamic attributes on the model by singleton, it works fine! but I can't access the object in the building time of fields to get what config_params keys there are to build the fields.

Comment: Please show any code you have tried. Also for those unfamiliar with rails-admin but willing to help, can you show the code that rails-admin uses to do this?

Comment: Could you share your code please?

Answer (score 0):

I resolced it with singleton methods and one partial.

Into model I added calbacks to load attributes in run time:

```
after_initialize :load_configs
after_find :load_configs
```

And the **load_configs** method

```
def load_configs
  config_params&.keys&.each do |param|
    define_singleton_method(param) do
      config_params[param]
    end

    define_singleton_method("#{param}=") do |value|
      config_params[param] = value
    end
  end
end
```

OK! Now you have a jsonb field and into this there are many keys end each key has an attribute on instance method.

Exemple:

```
instance.config_params = {'key_a': 1, key_b: 2}
instance.save

instance.reload.key_a
1
instance.key_a = 10
instance.key_a
10
instance.key_b
2
```

OK! Model ok!

Now you need load it into admin, ok?
let´s go!

into a file that you config the rails_admin to your model put it

```
edit do
  group 'Configurations' do
    field :config_params do
      partial 'config_params_partial'
    end
  end
end
```

Now you need create the partial file into de folder

```
app/views/rails_admin/main/_config_params_partial.html.erb
```

The partial code is like it

```
<% @object.config_params&.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :config_params, @object.config_params[key] do |config_params_fields| %>
      <div class="field controls">
        <%= config_params_fields.label @object.type.config_params[key]['label'] %>
        <br/>
        <%= config_params_fields.text_field key,
          :value => value,
          type: @object.type.config_params[key]['kind'],
          disabled: @object.type.config_params[key]['editable'] == false,
          class: 'form-control' %>
          <% if  @object.type.config_params[key]['required'] == true %>
            <span class="help-block">Obrigatório. </span>
          <% end %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**OBS:** I created a model called type that control each meta-info about my fields, but you can create it locked, only fill field properties.

Restart server and be happy!